# How to compare absolute coordinates

Tags: android, compare

I have a list of absolute points of screen like bellow :

```
355.2599  : 408.4894
353.31705 : 409.43512
341.44516 : 418.35184
329.3344  : 427.5607
314.9433  : 435.21622
304.6277  : 440.36212
292.61746 : 444.36887
```

And i have some other points like below :

```
160.66528 : 513.35834
319.33472 : 230.71161
304.3659  : 479.40076
```

How can i know second points is in first points?
for example when points different was less than 10 dp it should be return `found`;

```
private boolean checkValidate(List<Point> first, List<Point> second)
{
    int accuracy = Helper.dpToPixel(this, 10);
    int pointSize = first.size();
    int pointFlag = 0;
    List<Boolean> poinsValidation = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Point line : second)
    {
        if(pointSize != 0 && pointFlag < pointSize)
        {
            if(Math.abs(first.get(pointFlag).x - line.x ) <= accuracy && Math.abs(first.get(pointFlag).y - line.y ) <= accuracy)
            {
                poinsValidation.add(true);
                pointFlag++;
            }
        }

    }
    if(poinsValidation.size() == first.size())
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Because i want to know all of first points are recognized or no

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest nested looping through both arrays. Although nested looping is not preferred, at this stage I cannot think of another way to do it.

```
private boolean checkValidate(List<Point> first, List<Point> second)
{
    int accuracy = Helper.dpToPixel(this, 10);
    int pointSize = first.size();
    int pointSize2 = second.size();
    int pointFlag = 0;

    List<Boolean> poinsValidation = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Point line : second)
    {
        for(Point points: first){
            if(pointSize != 0 && pointSize2 != 0 &&  pointFlag < pointSize)
            {
                if(Math.abs(points.x - line.x ) <= accuracy && Math.abs(points.y - line.y ) <= accuracy)
                {
                    poinsValidation.add(true);
                    pointFlag++;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    if(poinsValidation.size() == first.size())
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Let me know if this helps.